# load content of file with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a php file sitting in a directory.  The file has some content to it that is just html.  All I would like to do is to use JQuery to get the file contents and place then in a div on my page.

```
 $(".page-intro").load("barware-title.php");
```

I have tried to use above code to load the page, but nothing happens.

Here is my Div

```
<div id="page-intro"></div>
```

I am at a loss for why this isn't working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any errors? What kind of HTML is `barware-title.php` outputting? Are you sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: @Pekka It's irrelevant about what kind of content is being loaded if it isn't even pointed at the correct place.

Comment: No errors, it's just HTML.  The files were included in the same directory.  All the answers were correct.  +1 to all.  Accepted solution to Ben.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to address by id (#), not class (.)

```
$("#page-intro").load("barware-title.php");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong. You should use

```
$('#page-intro')
```

The .page-intro is looking for a class name of page-intro.

Answer (score 3):

Change `.page-intro` to `#page-intro`. It's an id not a class.